# Why does $X_0\times S^1\simeq X-X_0$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional connected smooth manifold, and let $X_0$ be an embedded $(n-2)$-dimensional compact submanifold of $X$ with the trivial normal bundle. How do we get inclusion?

$$X_0\times S^1\hookrightarrow X-X_0$$

and show that it is actually a homotopy equivalence?

[image]

Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks

Comment: What are your own thoughts? And why do you expect a homotopy-equivalence? (It will be hardly every the case.)

Comment: My thought is that we remove a small neighborhood of $X_0$ containing $X_0$ to get the inclusion because the left part can deform to $X_0\times S^1$. I'm confused about whether it is right.

Answer (score 4):

In your comment you consider a small neighborhood $U$ of $X_0$ containing $X_0$. The regular neighborhood theorem says that there exists such a neighborhood $U$ together with a homeomorphism of pairs $(U,X_0) \mapsto (N,S)$ where $N$ is the normal bundle and $S$ is the zero section of $N$. By your hypothesis that $N$ is trivial and that $X_0$ has codimension 2, we obtain a homeomorphism $(N,S) \approx (X_0 \times \mathbb R^2,X_0 \times \{0\})$. Removing $X_0$ from $U$ and $S$ from $N$ we obtain a chain of homeomorphisms
$$U-X_0 \mapsto N-S \mapsto X_0 \times (\mathbb R^2 - \{0\})
$$
and the last term in this chain is evidently homotopy equivalent to $X_0 \times S^1$.

However, notice that this only gives a homotopy equivalence with $U-X_0$, not with $X-X_0$. It is entirely unnatural to expect a homotopy equivalence with $X-X_0$, and you might well even know counterexamples of this already. The case of a single point $X_0$ in almost any 2-manifold $X$ is a particularly trivial counterexample. For a slightly less trivial counterexample, consider $X_0 \subset S^3$ to be an ordinary unknotted circle, so $\pi_1(S^3-X_0) \approx \mathbb Z$ is infinite cyclic whereas $\pi_1(X_0 \times S^1) \approx \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \approx \mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: I pasted a picture just now in the above question. It says that taking a boundary of a small neighborhood of $X_0$ can make us obtain the homotopy equivalence.  Is it the same meaning you referred to? I'm a little confused about taking a boundary of a tubular neighborhood. Is there a difference between $N-X_0$ and taking boundary of $N$? Could you please explain it more? Thanks again.

Comment: I typed mistakenly $U$ to $N$ in the above comment. One of my questions should be: Is there a difference between $U-X_0$ and the taking boundary of $U$?

Comment: It sounds like you now want to ask a different question than the one you asked: from the statement of Theorem 7.6 one can see that your original question was missing a hypothesis, namely the "Furthermore..." sentence. Since the question you actually asked was been answered, perhaps the best thing to do is to move on and post a new question.

Comment: This the link of the new question I posted just now as you suggested. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4313177/a-question-about-homotopy-equivalence-ii